# Match onBeforeAction to only a group of routes using Iron Router for Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Using Iron Router for Meteor, I know I can use the parameter 'only' or 'except' to match named routers when defining an onBeforeAction, like the example in the guide:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(myAdminHookFunction, {
  only: ['admin']
});
```

Imagine I have a lot of views not needing this on before action, like public pages, and a lot needing it, like admin panel. Is there any way to apply this onBeforeAction to a group of routes without explicit list each one? I mean, for example, apply to all routes starting with '/admin', something like:

```
only: ['/admin/*']
```

Or maybe apply the onBeforeAction to a parent route and then define nested routes? (I can't find if Iron Route supports nested routes), something like:

```
Router.route('/admin/', {
    name: 'admin',
    onBeforeAction: function() {},
    routes: [
        {name: 'users', path: '/admin/users', action: function() {}},
        {name: 'posts', path: '/admin/posts', action: function() {}}
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating [`controllers`](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-controllers). Create a "base" controller and extend it wherever needed.

Comment: In my app I have an *anonymous* controller that handles not-logged in users. An *authenticated* controller builds on that to deal with logged-in users and then finally an *admin* controller that deals with admin users who by definition have to be logged in.

Comment: @MichelFloyd If you use the `alanning:roles` package and just check whether they're authorized or not, you might want to check out a very basic [package I made that makes it easy to limit routes to roles](https://atmospherejs.com/kookoskar/iron-router-roles)

Comment: Thanks @Oskar. I was just providing a simple example of layered IR controllers.